# Python sys.executable is empty

Tags: python, execve

I am testing out doing some shenanigans with `os.execve` and virtual environments. I am running into the problem where `sys.executable` is empty if I replace the current python process with another python subprocess.

The example below shows what's going on (run this inside a python shell):

```
import os, sys
print(sys.executable) # works this time
os.execve("/usr/bin/python", [], {}) # drops me into a new python shell
import sys # yes, again
print(sys.executable) # is empty
```

The full output of me running the commands above in a python shell:

```
 lptp [ tmp ]: python
Python 2.7.10 (default, Oct 14 2015, 16:09:02) 
[GCC 5.2.1 20151010] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import os, sys
>>> print(sys.executable) # works this time
/usr/bin/python
>>> os.execve("/usr/bin/python", [], {}) # drops me into a new python shell
Python 2.7.10 (default, Oct 14 2015, 16:09:02) 
[GCC 5.2.1 20151010] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import sys # yes, again
>>> print(sys.executable) # is empty

>>>
```

`sys.executable` being empty is causing me problems, most notably that `platform.libc_ver()` fails because `sys.executable` is empty:

```
>>> import platform
>>> platform.libc_ver()
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/platform.py", line 163, in libc_ver
    f = open(executable,'rb')
IOError: [Errno 21] Is a directory: '/tmp'
```

Note that the example above was run after calling `os.execve(...)`

Comment: What if you pass *os.environ* as the env  `os.execve("/usr/bin/python", [], os.environ )`?

Comment: hrmm, well that works... but only in my simplified example above. In my real code that doesn't make a difference, since I'm already passing in a modified version of my current environment. I'll update my question with a better example.

Comment: Well if sys.executable is None or an empty string then it cannot be found so it is definitely related to passing an empty dict as env.

Comment: I get an equivalent issue from running python using `env -i` such as `env -i python /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/virtualenv.py ~/jenkins/workspace/analysis_super__Python_tests/venv`, in which case virtualenv.py does not have a valid sys.executable.

Comment: Probing deeper, I see that this is easier to get around with `env -i` than it is with the OP's execve issue.  Whereas `env -i python -c 'import sys ; print(sys.executable)'` gives an empty result, just giving the full path with `env -i /usr/bin/python -c 'import sys ; print(sys.executable)'` gives the expected result.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Python relies on `argv[0]` and several environment variables to determine `sys.executable`. When you pass an empty argv and environment, Python doesn't know how to determine its path. At the very least, you should provide `argv[0]`:

```
os.execve('/usr/bin/python', ['/usr/bin/python'], {})
```